# Odd behaviour for converting a list of named characters to a data frame

Tags: r, list, purrr

I work with lists from APIs reasonably often, but I can't convert this simple list to a df.

Reprex data:

```
my_ls <- list(list(ip = "104.28.131.102", type = "ipv4", continent_code = "NA", 
continent_name = "North America", country_code = "US", country_name = "United States", 
region_code = "CA", region_name = "California", city = "San Jose", 
zip = "95122", latitude = 37.3305282592773, longitude = -121.838226318359, 
location = list(geoname_id = 5392171L, capital = "Washington D.C.", 
    languages = list(list(code = "en", name = "English", 
        native = "English")), country_flag = "https://assets.ipstack.com/flags/us.svg", 
    country_flag_emoji = "", country_flag_emoji_unicode = "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8", 
    calling_code = "1", is_eu = FALSE)), list(ip = "109.206.213.143", 
type = "ipv4", continent_code = "EU", continent_name = "Europe", 
country_code = "PL", country_name = "Poland", region_code = "MZ", 
region_name = "Mazovia", city = "Piastów", zip = "05-850", 
latitude = 52.2565498352051, longitude = 20.7680397033691, 
location = list(geoname_id = 762381L, capital = "Warsaw", 
    languages = list(list(code = "pl", name = "Polish", native = "Polski")), 
    country_flag = "https://assets.ipstack.com/flags/pl.svg", 
    country_flag_emoji = "", country_flag_emoji_unicode = "U+1F1F5 U+1F1F1", 
    calling_code = "48", is_eu = TRUE)))
```

I want to get this into a simple data frame with 22 cols and 2 rows.

I've tried several things, but this illustrates the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- my_ls %>% 
  map(unlist) %>%
  map(tibble)
```

The resulting data frame still has a list level of a character within it where I would have expected `unlist` to remove that into a named character vector ready for `tibble` to do its job, but there's still a list element in there for every tibble.

```
head(my_df)

    [[1]]
# A tibble: 22 × 1
   `<chr>`       
   <chr>         
 1 104.28.131.102
 2 ipv4          
 3 NA            
 4 North America 
 5 US            
 6 United States 
 7 CA            
 8 California    
 9 San Jose      
10 95122         
# … with 12 more rows
```

I'm stumped - I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `unlist` returns a `vector` and `tibble/data.frame` directly applied on that vector returns a single column.  Instead, the vector needs to be either transposed (`t`) or convert to `list` (`as.data.frame.list` in the current solution) to return as many columns as the `length` of the `vector`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- map_dfr(my_ls, ~ unlist(.x) %>%
   as.data.frame.list())  %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> str(out)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ ip                                 : chr  "104.28.131.102" "109.206.213.143"
 $ type                               : chr  "ipv4" "ipv4"
 $ continent_code                     : chr  NA "EU"
 $ continent_name                     : chr  "North America" "Europe"
 $ country_code                       : chr  "US" "PL"
 $ country_name                       : chr  "United States" "Poland"
 $ region_code                        : chr  "CA" "MZ"
 $ region_name                        : chr  "California" "Mazovia"
 $ city                               : chr  "San Jose" "Piastów"
 $ zip                                : chr  "95122" "05-850"
 $ latitude                           : num  37.3 52.3
 $ longitude                          : num  -121.8 20.8
 $ location.geoname_id                : int  5392171 762381
 $ location.capital                   : chr  "Washington D.C." "Warsaw"
 $ location.languages.code            : chr  "en" "pl"
 $ location.languages.name            : chr  "English" "Polish"
 $ location.languages.native          : chr  "English" "Polski"
 $ location.country_flag              : chr  "https://assets.ipstack.com/flags/us.svg" "https://assets.ipstack.com/flags/pl.svg"
 $ location.country_flag_emoji        : chr  "" ""
 $ location.country_flag_emoji_unicode: chr  "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8" "U+1F1F5 U+1F1F1"
 $ location.calling_code              : int  1 48
 $ location.is_eu                     : logi  FALSE TRUE
```